# How to integrate and test paypal on Android?

Tags: android, testing, paypal

Everything it's messed up! There are no good documentations, no tutorials for paypal integration in android apps. I have created many sandbox accounts (buyer / receiver) but I can't log in on sandbox.paypal.com. I have deleted my cookies, tried with another browser, but I can't login. PayPal sandbox it's not working at all.

**I don't know which library to use?**

```
PayPalAndroidSDK.jar (1.0.3) - new (for US developers)
PayPal_MPL.jar (V ???) - old library (for NON-US developers)
```

I'm using the old library, with the following implementation:

## 1 AndroidManifest.XML

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

## 2 I have imported `PayPal_MPL.jar` and added to the project Build path.

## 3 Activity to fire up the paypal dialog

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
      // setting layout, etc.

      // init paypal
      PayPal pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(MyPayPalActivity.this, "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);

      btnPaypal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v){
            PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();

            payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("1.00"));
            payment.setCurrencyType("USD");
            payment.setRecipient("zbarcea-cris-facilitator@yahoo.com");
            payment.setPaymentSubtype(PayPal.PAYMENT_SUBTYPE_DONATIONS);

            Intent checkout = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment, MyActivity.this);
            startActivityForResult(checkout, 1);
         }
      });
   }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     switch(resultCode)
     {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
           Log.e("D:", "RES OK");
        break;

        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
           Log.e("D:", "RES CANCELED");
        break;

        case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:
           Log.e("D:", "FAILURE !");
        break;
 }
  }
}
```

**If I press the button, the paypal dialog is showed, but how to log in? What sandbox account should I use? I have tried with the receiver / business account, but it's not working.**

The dialog it's working, but I can't log in with my sandbox account! What did I do wrong? Am I missing something?

> What is my application id?
>
> PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX this resource is used for sandbox test only? What resource should I put for live?

Answer (score 0):

You can't log in to pay with the same account that is going to receive the payment.  You need to log in with one of the Personal/buyer accounts you say you created in the sandbox.